# How to print a double pointer?

Tags: c

How can I print the address of `mat`? It is double pointer.

```
int **mat;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int i;
    mat = (int**) malloc(10 * sizeof(int*));

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      mat[i]= (int*)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));

    int id =fork();

    if(id == 0){
        printf("%p\n", &mat);
        mat[1][2]=5;
        printf("%d\n", mat[1][2]);
    }
    else{
        sleep(3);
        printf("%p\n", &mat);
        printf("%d\n", mat[1][2]);
    }

}
```

What I have now prints the same address for both parts of the fork. Output:

```
0x601058
5
0x601058
0
```

Comment: There are no double pointers, just pointers to something. `int ** mat` is a pointer to (pointer to ( int ) ). (And why would you want the address of a pointer to a pointer?) This is... weird? Perhaps add some commentary of what you *intend* to do with the code presented.

Comment: When I read "double pointer" I think "pointer to `double`".

Comment: but it gives me the same address, I think fork() give me new allocation - its print --- 0x601058 \n 5\n 0x601058 \n 0\n

Comment: And remember that you create a totally independent process. Changes made to the variables or data in one process will not be reflected back to the other. Even if a pointer is the same, the *virtual memory map* is different. You seem to be misunderstanding a bit on how processes and virtual memory work. Perhaps you should consider doing more research about that?

Comment: @DevSolar double pointer seems a fitting description of a pointer to a pointer and it can at least be said in 2 words instead of 4. As for the address of a pointer to a pointer, maybe they need to point to their pointer to pointer to point their pointer to pointer to pointer.

Comment: @TarickWelling: I prefer the term "2 star pointer".

Comment: @TarickWelling "double pointer" can be mistaken for "pointer to double", so it is best to avoid this term.

Comment: I wanted to check if the value of the pointer - mat is the same for the child and parent

Comment: I think you are creating a 10x10 2D array of ints and then setting one value in it n one thread and reading it on the other thread.  Regardless of wanting to print a "pointer to a pointer to an int" do you realise that there is no certainty that the first thread writes the data before the second thread reads it?  You need to look into thread synchronisation/mutexes.

Comment: The correct way to print the pointer would be `printf("%p\n", (void*)&mat);`. In practice your method works too, even though it is undefined behaviour according to the standard. What is your question though?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. True but in a context without doubles it is more than fine to use it like this as it is shorter and easier to say which allows you to thinks about it instead of just dogmatically saying the correct form.

Comment: @CodeGorilla I did sleep.. I saw that it print 5 before 0..

Comment: @CodeGorilla it is a process not a thread. The second process will never see what the first process writes.

Comment: how this is possible? the address of mat is the same but when the child puts the value of 5 on mat , The parent dont see it? They write on the same address

Comment: You want to read about virtual memory.

Comment: @ILoveBitcoin `fork` creates a entirely new process with it's own virtual memory.

Comment: @ILoveBitcoin you should read this answer, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31409/352890

Comment: "What I have now prints the same address for both parts of the fork." Yeah but even if you print the address correctly, it will still do that. Because you allocate before the fork. Why did you expect it to do differently? Also there are very few cases where you would ever want to use fork(). The sane way to creating two different process is to write two different programs. Don't use old Unix smell libraries just for the sake of smelly libraries. The main use-case of fork() nowadays is posing.

Comment: Guys. I don't understand if they are works on the same address on the memory how it is possible?  Maybe the name of the address is the same but in different stacks? I did not choose to study fork, I'm a student..

Comment: "how it is possible?" **Read about virtual memory** and you will find the answer. It would be counterproductive to start explaining virtual memory to you here. There is a lot of material out there, we don't need another half-assed writeup.

Comment: @ILoveBitcoin I think you are suffering form the operating system limiting the memory that a process can access to protect you from viruses.
You need to look into shared memory and inter process synchronization that should help you achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`%p` expects a `void*` pointer, so you need to cast your pointer:

```
printf("%p\n", (void*) &mat);
```

You are getting the same address printed in both cases because the forked process inherits a copy of the parent process’ virtual memory. Once you modify the memory their state diverges (which is why the *values* inside the array are different after you modify them), but the virtual memory addresses don’t change (if they did, all pointers pointing to that memory would be invalidated when forking, which would be less than ideal).

Inside the forked process you also mustn’t read `mat[1][2]` because the value hasn’t been initialised yet, so reading it is undefined behaviour.

Furthermore, don’t explicitly cast the result of `malloc` in C. This isn’t a bug but it’s unnecessary.